# php+mysql: select max(value) shows old results

Tags: php, mysql

my code is:

```
echo $sql = "SELECT MAX(version) as version FROM stats";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rr=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$v = $rr["version"];
```

The problem is: By the first run everything is fine. let's say `$v = 10`;

But then it doesn't change when  the field `version` is being updated by other sources. I could increase it to 12 and I see in the database it is 12. By running this PHP-script it always sets `$v` to "10". Why is that?

Comment: Re-run your code and it should be 12.

Comment: Do you have some kind of caching enabled in your environment?

Comment: This is exactly what I do :) I rerun it and get 10.

Comment: About caching: I tried to do mysql_free_result(); at the beginning of this code, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

In this code you always display your query (you have echo at the beginning).

In my opinion there are only 2 options:

1. You use some type of PHP cache. If you do, you probably won't see `SELECT MAX(version) as version FROM stats` every time you refresh the page
2. You don't display $v value right after this code is being executed. `$v` variable is for example used often in loops so it's quite possible you change the value in some other part of your code and that's why it's always 10.

So what you should do you should :

```
echo $sql = "SELECT MAX(version) as version FROM stats";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rr=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$v = $rr["version"];
echo $v;
```

And make sure you see messages each time you refresh your page. If it's not displayed it means you use cache, otherwise you should see correct value here.

Of course, you also shouldn't use `mysql` functions any more because mysql extendsion is deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO instead.